# Create flat file based on results of a query

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a SQL query which returns a complete dataset: e.g.

ID, EmployeeNumber, Column1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Insurance1, Insurance2, Charges1,..Charges5 ... InsurancePmt1, InsurancePmt2,..Deductible, Copay,..Col70

I need to create a file based on the dataset returned and the file should have the following structure:
L1--> *TR STATS*, TotalChgs, TotalEmployees...
L2 --> *EMP*, EmployeeNumber1, Column1, Column2, Col3, Charges1, Charges 5...
L3 --> *INS*, Insurance1, InsurancePmt1
L4 --> *INS*, Insurance2, InsurancePmt2
L5 --> *PMT*, Deductible, Copay
L6 --> *EMP*, EmployeeNumber2, Column1, Column2, Col3, Charges1, Charges 5...
L7 --> *INS*, Insurance1, InsurancePmt1
L8 --> *INS*, Insurance2, InsurancePmt2
L9 --> *PMT*, Deductible, Copay

And so on for every "Employee Number" returned in the dataset.
The format/layout of the file is a requirement. I am using MSSQL but stumped on the logistics of the file. Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve using sql?
If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're really asking how to format the output of a query, so you probably need to look at reporting tools (SSRS, Crystal Reports etc.) or a template engine for your preferred programming language. If you must do it within SSIS then a Script task would be one way, although personally I would put the query in a view (or stored procedure) and query that from a client tool to generate the output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that I understand you correctly, but this is my solution for your question (maybe not the best):

```
select case piv.rank_
 when 1 then 'L1--> ' + sel1.a + sel1.c 
 when 2 then 'L2--> ' + sel1.b + sel1.d
 when 3 then 'L3--> ' + sel1.a + sel1.b + sel1.d
 when 4 then 'L4--> ' + sel1.c + sel1.b + ' any data u need'
 when 5 then 'EmployeeNumber = ' + sel1.EmployeeNumber
 else 'nothing'  
 end as linesToFile, piv.rank_, sel1.EmployeeNumber
                from
       (
       select sel.a, sel.b, sel.c, sel.d, sel.EmployeeNumber from (
           SELECT 'data_1_1' a, 'data_1_2' b, 'data_1_3' c, 'data_1_4' d, '33333333' EmployeeNumber
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'data_2_1' a, 'data_2_2' b, 'data_2_3' c, 'data_2_4' d, '44444444' EmployeeNumber
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'data_3_1' a, 'data_3_2' b, 'data_3_3' c, 'data_4_4' d, '55555555' EmployeeNumber) sel
       ) sel1,
       (SELECT TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sel4.a ASC) AS rank_ from(SELECT '1' a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '2' a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '29' a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '9' a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '19' a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT '29' a) sel4) piv
order by EmployeeNumber, rank_;
```

Where `sel1` is your table, `piv` is table used to generate rownum (you can use some table in your schema that surely have more rows than you need to display per one `Employee Number`), `TOP 5`  number of lines per `EmployeeNumber` you need to display (equal to number of `CASEs`).

In `CASE` write your structure of file.